# What is this cabinet “bolt” called?

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, hardware, custom-cabinetry

been tuning up some cabinets at home and realized that the reason several aren’t hanging straight are because they are missing the “bolt” pictured below. Been searching several different queries online trying to find what they are called so I can purchase some replacements but haven’t had any luck. Seems like a shame to buy new hinges when its simply one component that is missing. Attached is a picture the bolt I removed from another hinge which is functioning well and the hinge which is missing said bolt. Thanks in advance to anyone who takes the time to answer :).[image] [image]

Comment: I can’t name them, but I can assure you that you aren’t going to find them from the original manufacturer. It’s unlikely that you’ll find replacements from name brands like Blum. (Two issues: size/thread, and availability.)

Comment: You could try looking at the cheapy hinges at a big box store and seeing if it’s viable to plunder that part and toss the rest. (The way your hinge attaches to the door is slightly uncommon, so screw holes would be messy.)

Answer (score 2):

It's a cabinet hinge lateral adjustment screw. They vary by manufacturer and I haven't seen them sold as replacement parts. You might be able to take it to a cabinet maker and get a match or find the manufacturer of your hinge and get with them. Buying new hinges might be your only option.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like these are Meaton hinges, which come from China.  Take one to a cabinet store and see if they might be able to help you source that part.  Or you could try contacting the manufacturer directly at https://www.meaton-group.com/.